# Este código me lanza error java.lang.ClassException

Tags: java

En la línea

```
Statement sentencia = (Statement) cnx.createStatement();
```

Me dice que tengo que hacer sí o sí casting, al igual que en

```
ResultSet resultado = ((java.sql.Statement) sentencia).executeQuery(sql);
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué? No se como solucionarlo

```
package test;
    
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.net.ConnectException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    
    import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver;
    import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Result;
    import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Statement;
    
    public class TestMysqlJDBC {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //1 utilizamos la cadena de conexion a la base de datos
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrival=true";
        //esta es la clase con la quee nos conectaremos
            try {
                //Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdc.Driver");
                Connection cnx = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "juan");
                Statement sentencia = (Statement) cnx.createStatement();
                String sql = "select * from test";
                ResultSet resultado = ((java.sql.Statement) sentencia).executeQuery(sql);
                while(resultado.next()) {
                    System.out.println(resultado.getInt("id_persona"));
                    
                }
            }catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cambia este import `import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Statement` por `java.sql.Statement`.

Comment: Ya me funciona, era por ese import. Muchísimas gracias

Comment: @jucasmarcastilla te recomiendo hacer uso de los PreparedStatement, además de ayudarte a evitar inyecciones SQL son mucho más rápidos que los Statement